# Redirect subdirectory to another subdirectory with mod_rewrite rewriterules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In an `.htaccess` inside the subdirectory `alpha` (a few directories down from root: `http://domain.com/subsite/alpha/.htaccess`) I want to catch all requests for files in:

- `http://domain.com/subsite/alpha/images/`

and redirect them to:

- `http://domain.com/subsite/alpha/img/`

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

`RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/\.\./\.\./img/$1 [R=302,NC,L]`

This only works if there are no further directories inside `/images`. I could make it work from root like so

`RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /subsite/alpha/img/$1 [R=302,NC,L]`

but then I'd have to manually update this from `alpha` to `beta`, `preprod`, etc.

Basically, I need a way to isolate everything between `^` and `images/`. I tried some variations on this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)images/(.*)$ /$1/img/$2 [R=302,NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)images/(.*)$ ^$1/img/$2 [R=302,NC,L]`

But it doesn't work because the `.htaccess` is in `alpha` and doesn't know about what's between it and root. Thus in the above, `$1` isn't `/subsite/alpha` but whatever is between `/alpha` and `images/`.

Comment: Try adding the following to `.htaccess` in the parent directory above the directory of interest: `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/` or `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /bar/baz/`. Also see [How to get apache2 to redirect to a subdirectory](http://serverfault.com/q/9992/145545).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RewriteBase` and use relative path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subsite/alpha/

RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ img/$1 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Or else if you want to avoid using `RewriteBase` then use this rule to generate dynamic `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

RewriteRule ^(.*?/)?images/(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}$1img/$2 [R=302,NC,L,NE]
```

**How dynamic `RewriteBase` works:**

- It compares `REQUEST_URI` variable (which is complete path) with the URI matched by `RewriteRule` (which is relative to current path) and gets differential in `%{ENV:BASE}` variable.
- You can use `$0` captured from `RewriteRule` in your `RewriteCond` because `mod_rewrite` actually **processes a ruleset backwards**. It starts with the pattern in the `RewriteRule`, and if it matches, goes on to check the one or more `RewriteCond`.
- So as you can see in a `RewriteCond`, the LHS (test string) can use back-reference variables e.g. `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` etc but RHS side i.e. condition string **cannot use** these `$1`, `$2` OR `%1`, `%2` variables.
- Inside the RHS condition part only back-reference we can use are **internal back-references** i.e. the groups we have captured in this condition itself. They are denoted by `\1`, `\2` etc.
- In your `RewriteCond` first captured group is `([^#]*)`. It will be represented by internal back-reference `\1.
- As you can mark out that this rule is basically finding `RewriteBase` dynamically by comparing `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$0`. An example of `%{REQUEST_URI}` will be `/directory/foobar.php` and example of `$0` for same example URI will be `foobar.php`. `^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$` is putting the difference in 2nd captured group `%2` or `\2`. Here t will populate `%2` or `\2` with the value `/directory/` which is used later in setting up env variable `%{ENV:BASE}` i.e. `E=BASE:%2`.

Comment: Yes, with a little modification it is working.  It seems `%{ENV:BASE}` already has a trailing slash, so that got duplicated in the final rule. Also, I neglected to mention this in the question, but I wanted to catch all `/images` directories under `/alpha`, not just `/alpha/images`. I believe I got that working by writing a second rule (`RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}$1/img/$2 [R=302,NC,L]`).

Comment: ok I modified answer accordingly and added detailed explanation.

Comment: Sure thing. If I had 15 rep I'd send an upvote your way as well.

Comment: You don't need to vote up. You can mark the answer as accepted by **clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer** and it will turn green.

Comment: Thanks. I was just double checking that it worked in all the cases I explained in my question.